# Getting serialize trait is not implemented for my struct

Tags: rust

The error I get is  at ***t***: `serialize_into(&mut f, t).unwrap();` :

```
the trait bound `T: models::_::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied. 
the trait `models::_::_serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `T`rustcE0277. 
lib.rs(1, 1): required by a bound in this.
lib.rs(93, 8): required by this bound in `bincode::serialize_into`.
utils.rs(12, 19): consider restricting type parameter `T`.
```

But I have used `#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]` on the struct.

```
use bincode::serialize_into;
use std::io::BufWriter;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
#[serde(tag = "m_tag")]
pub struct Profile {
        energy: HashMap<&'static str, i32>,
        guid: u64,  
}

// in another file:
pub fn save_json(t:  &Profile) {
    let mut f = BufWriter::new(File::create("/tmp/foo.bar").unwrap());
    serialize_into(&mut f, t).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Check the list here: https://serde.rs/derive.html. You might be missing some steps.
Deriving `Deserialize` will not work, since you cannot deserialize a `&'static str`.

Comment: Ok. I think it's because you can't serialize str types in the first place. So, I changed it to  String. then the  compiler does not ask for lifetime. I assumed str types get converted to String  under the hood when saving